# Dictonary wise subtraction

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two dictonaries in one dictonary:

```
d = {'A': {}, 'B': {}}
```

Where:

```
A = {'key1': [[3],[ ],[ ], [ ]], 'key2': [[1,2,3], [ ],[4,5,6],[]], 'key4:' ...}
```

So a Dictonary with a list of say length 4 (=n in the following), which has lists of other data in it at some points, which are not all the same length.

And B:

```
B = {'key1': [[ ],[ ], [ ], [ ]], 'key2': [[7,8,9], [ ],[10,11,12],[]], 'key4:' ...}
```

So the two are of the same length in terms of the content of the single keys and have the same naming of the keys.
Now I want to subtract A from B, so that
A[key1] with list of length n is subtracted element by element from B[key1] with list of length n, then key2 and so on.

New dictonary

```
C = {'key1':[Diff1,Diff2,Diff3,Diffn], 'key2': ...}
```

So that the diff is [ ] if there are not two numbers.

For key2 in the example therfore :

```
C = {...'key2': [[1-7,8-2,3-9],[ ], [4-10,5-11,6-12], []], ...}
```

(Of course calculate the difference and not display it)

Then a dictonary

```
D = {'key1': [mean(C['key1']), 'key2': mean(C['key2']),...}
```

would have to be created, so the mean values of the C keys.

Unfortunately, I don't have that much experience with diconarys yet, so I would be grateful for any hint.

I wrote a code to average the values, however this way I skip the difference (which I need) and it also produces the warning for empty lists in the lists.

```
for key, value in d['A'].items():
        d['A'][key] = [(np.array(i).mean()) for i in value if not int(len(i)) ==0]
```

Comment: What about key1: You have non-matching lists there in the first index: `[3]` and `[]`. How does subtraction work there?

Comment: It should return an emtpy list entry, like C = { 'key1': [ [ ], [ ], [ ], [ ] ] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to obtain the difference by subtracting A from B and storing it into C by using the following code

```
for key, value in d['A'].items():
difference=[]
for i in range(len(d['A'][key])):
    outer=[]
    for j in range(len(d['A'][key][i])):
        outer.append(d['B'][key][i][j]-d['A'][key][i][j])
    difference.append(outer)
d['C'][key]=difference
```

Now this was the assumption dictionary I took from your question and used to test that it works

```
d={
'A' : {'key1': [[3],[2],[1], [5]], 'key2': [[1,2,3], [2],[4,5,6],[2]]},
'B' : {'key1': [[5],[ 1],[8], [9]], 'key2': [[2,3,11], [11],[8,2,22],[4]]},
'C':{}
}
```

And used a print statement to check the output. I guess you have got the mean part already figured out, hence leaving it with this much.

P.s: When the list element from A is empty, you get an empyty list as an output whereas when B is empty, It throws an error which can be handled using exception handling.

> This is how you can handle the exception:

```
try:
   outer.append(d['B'][key][i][j]-d['A'][key][i][j])
except:
   outer.append([])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but there occurs the error in line "outer.append" : 'list index out of range' if d['A or B']['key'][i][j] is []  (which also occurs manually for e.g. i and j [0][0] and that place is []). Any ideas?

Comment: Manually checked only d['A or B']['key'][i] outputs the empty list. ( so if I don't use j)

Comment: I'm updating the solution since I'm unable to multiple lines of code with proper indentations in here